# Show HTML element if the Array provided has a nested Array using Angular.js

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, nested, populate

I want to populate a dropdown with an array, and if the user chooses an option that has a nested array, Then and only then I want to show another dropdown and populate it with that child array, and so on.

And then populate a hidden field with the last value of the chain.

How would I approach this with Angular.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` to conditionally show/hide the second drop-down

The code can be seen/tested [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHNTSjTF3vCF20jENNf0?p=preview)

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name:'item1'},
    {name:'item2', subItems: [
      {name:'sub item 1'},
      {name:'sub item 2'}]}];
});
```

Markup:

```
<p>
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.name for i in items"></select>
</p>
<p ng-show="selectedItem.subItems">
  <select ng-model="selectedSubItem" ng-options="i.name for i in selectedItem.subItems"></select>
</p>
```

Comment: That kinda works, but when I choose anything from the second dropdown it disappear.

Comment: You are correct, I had both selects bound to the same ng-model, so when the second select was changed it also changed the first one. Both the plnkr link and answer have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-change` directive in your `select` tag and in `ng-change` call a function that checks your scenario.

If you provide your array data, the answer can be given more accurately.

I know this approach is a long run. But it helps you to keep your code clean.

MARKUP

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items" ng-change="doesItemHaveSubArray(selectedItem)"></select>

<div ng-if="subItem">
  <select ng-model="selectedSubItem" ng-options="item.name for item in subItem"></select>
</div>
```

In JS

```
$scope.doesItemHaveSubArray=function(item){
        if(item!==undefined){
          $scope.subItem=item.subItems;
        }
      }
```

Comment: It's an array like this ...


items = [
    {name:'item1'},
    {name:'item2', subItems: [
      {name:'sub item 1'},
      {name:'sub item 2', subSubItems: [
       {name:'sub sub item 1'},
       {name:'sub sub item 2'}
       ]}
      ]}
    ];